# H2 database - SQL Error: 50200 SQLState:HYT00 - Timeout trying to lock table

Tags: h2

Im getting this strange h2 error (vers 1.2.147) , the code basically does this :-

create session1
insert into table ABC
commit

XXX

create session2
read from table XYZ    -> produces locked table ABC timeout exception.
close session2

close session1

The bizarre thing about this scenario is that if XXX is empty (ie no code) I get the timeout exception however if it contains a Select statement, it all works fine.

?????